# Docusign .NET Sdk Create document and get recipient view (Embed signing) (ACCOUNT_NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_ENVELOPE)

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to create envelope and get recipient URL for further processing. 
But always getting rest error "ACCOUNT_NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_ENVELOPE".

```
        string RecipientEmail = "123@123.com";
        string RecipientName = "123";
        string AccountEmail = "myuser@mydomain.com";
        string AccountPassword = "mypassword";
        string documentPath = @"C:\Users\...."; ;

        var account = new Account();
        account.Email = AccountEmail;
        account.Password = AccountPassword;   
        var result = account.Login();
        if (!result)
        return;

        var envelope = new Envelope();
        envelope.Login = account;
        envelope.Recipients = new Recipients()
        {
            signers = new []
            {
                new Signer()
                {
                    email = RecipientEmail,
                    name = RecipientName,
                    recipientId = "1",
                    clientUserId = "777"
                }
            }
        };
        rsult = envelope.Create(documentPath);
        if(!result)return;
        result = envelope.GetRecipientView("mydomain");
```

REST API

here is code example :
github.com/kosmur/DocuSignTestWithProblems

Comment: Are you testing this with your developer sandbox account, or a free trial account through the main website?  API requests can only be used with your developer sandbox until you certify your application, then your Integrator Key works with any account.  See the Go Live section of the Developer Center for more info on Certification.

Comment: Yes, I'm using free trial account, and everything works fine until I call GetRecipientView. I'm requesting demo.docusign.

Comment: Right, so that's your problem.  You can not use your free trial account with the API.  You need to use your developer sandbox that you created through the Developer Center

Comment: https://github.com/kosmur/DocuSignTestWithProblems I've uploaded my code if it would some how help to show the problem

Comment: I've modified my answer, are you sure you are actually creating the envelope first (i.e. DocuSign server side) before requesting the signing URL?  Do you see the envelope created when you log in to your demo Console??

Answer (score 1):

You can not use Free Trial accounts (which are created through www.docusign.com) with the API.  You need to use your free developer sandbox created through the DocuSign Developer Center

https://www.docusign.com/devcenter

Additionally, I don't believe you are following the correct pattern for Embedded Signing flow.  You need to create the envelope first (i.e. DocuSign server side) before you can request a signing URL.  I see in your GitHub code you are instantiating an envelope object but I don't see the call to actually create one.

If you look at `Examples.cs` in the root level of the [DocuSign .NET Client](https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-.NET-Client) and scroll down to **Example #8** you'll see how it already references an existing envelope, i.e.

```
    //==========================================================================================
    // *** Walkthrough #8 - Embedded Signing
    //==========================================================================================
    private void EmbeddedSigning()
    {
        //*****************************************************************
        // ENTER VALUES FOR FOLLOWING VARIABLES!
        //*****************************************************************
        string AccountEmail = "***";
        string AccountPassword = "***";
        string EnvelopeId = "***";
        string RecipientEmail = "***";
        string RecipientName = "***";
        //*****************************************************************

        // user credentials 
        Account account = new Account();
        account.Email = AccountEmail;
        account.Password = AccountPassword;

        // make the login call (retrieves your baseUrl and accountId)
        bool result = account.Login();
        if (!result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Login API call failed for user {0}.\nError Code:  {1}\nMessage:  {2}", account.Email, account.RestError.errorCode, account.RestError.message);
            return;
        }

        // create envelope object and assign login info
        Envelope envelope = new Envelope();
        envelope.Login = account;

        // assign the envelope id that was passed in
        envelope.EnvelopeId = EnvelopeId;

        // add one signer (single recipient embedded signing currently supported in DocuSign .NET Client)
        envelope.Recipients = new Recipients()
        {
            signers = new Signer[]
            {
                new Signer()
                {
                    email = RecipientEmail,
                    name = RecipientName,
                    recipientId = "1"
                }
            }
        };

        // generate the recipient view token
        result = envelope.GetRecipientView("http://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.Integration.Client.dll/");

        if (!result)
        {
            if (envelope.RestError != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error code:  {0}\nMessage:  {1}", envelope.RestError.errorCode, envelope.RestError.message);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error encountered retrieving signing token, please review your envelope and recipient data.");
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // open the recipient view (SenderViewUrl field is re-used for the recipient URL)
            Process.Start(envelope.SenderViewUrl);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Ergin, I've registered new account , but getting same REstError :(

Comment: Thank for your answer Ergin, I've used this example code and get same Rest Error, also in my code in Git on line 54 you can see I'm calling Create method

Answer (score 0):

User is supposed to pass either custom "X-DocuSign-Authentication" header or Authorization header with bearer docusign token with each docusign call.

Comment: You mean I should call account.Login(); method, before each API call ?

Comment: No, I mean in the request header of your docusign api call, you need to pass a header as per docusign's documentation.

Comment: Of course I'm passing, all the procedures works excellent , except getRecipientView.